# Rspec String argument constraint to match multiple regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec3

How can I pass an argument constraint that matches several regex constraints ?

```
expect(subject).to(
  receive(:matching_multiple_regex)
  .with( a_string_that_matches_all[/hello/, /world/])
)

subject.matching_multiple_regex('hello /o\ world')
# => should pass
```

How do I implement `a_string_that_matches_all[/hello/, /world])` ?

EDIT My concrete use case : I am trying to implement a matcher for slack messages

```
expect { some_code }.to(
      send_a_slack_notification
      .with_message_containing("Hello world")
      .with_link_to('hello_world')
    )
```

The `send_a_slack_notification` is a custom matcher `expect(SlackService).to receive(ping)`
And accepts chain arguments :
- `with_message_containing` is expected to run a simple string regex match
- `with_link_to`is expected to run a slack href match

The code I'm working at right now looks like

```
require 'rspec/expectations'

RSpec::Matchers.define :send_a_slack_notification do
  supports_block_expectations

  match do |actual|
    slack_spy = spy(SlackConnector)
    stub_const('SlackConnector', slack_spy)
    expectation_hash = {}
    expectation_hash[:channel] = @channel if @channel

    actual.call

    expect(slack_spy).to(
      have_received(:ping)
      .with(
        a_string_that_matches_all([@text, @link_regexp].compact)),
        hash_including(expectation_hash)
      )
    )
  end

  chain :with_message_containing do |text|
    @text = text
  end

  chain :with_link_to do |href, text = nil|
    @link_regexp = /<.*#{::Regexp.escape(href)}.*\|#{text ? ::Regexp.escape(text) : '.+' }>/
  end

  chain :to_channel do |channel|
    @channel = channel
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to create your own [custom matcher](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/frames#Composing_Matchers) to match multiple regular expressions the way you're looking for. However, I would encourage you to do it with a single regular expression instead.

```
expect(subject).to match(/^hello.+world$/)
```

Comment: Hey I have a dded a concrete example with my use case. Especially I want to test the presence of a link and a text separately on the same argument, so I think I need different regex to make it readable.